# Writing a polynomial as a product of irreducible elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Write $2+4x+6x^2+x^3$ as a product of irreducible elements considering an element in each of the following rings.  In each of the following rings. 
$\mathbb{Z}[x], \mathbb{Q}[x], \mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$

My thinking was first to factorize the polynomial. After factoring I could see how I could transform them into irreducibles which means give that a root that do not exist in this ring. But I am not sure how to start really.. S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This polynomial is irreducible by the Eisenstein's criterion for two first cases.

In the third case it's $x^3-2x-1=(x+1)(...)$

Comment: How does knowing it is irreducible from Eisenstein help me to find the irreducible factors?

Comment: $x^3-2x-1=x^3+x^2-x^2-x-x-1=(x+1)(x^2-x-1),$ where $x+1$ and $x^2-x-1$ they are irreducible in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The Eisenstein's criterion gives that the polynomial is irreducible above $\mathbb Z$ and above $\mathbb Q$ and we have no any relation here with my previous comment.

Comment: Okay I understand for $Z[3]$ the polynomial = $x^3+x+2$ which has a root of the set {0,1,2} when x=2. and then we can factor it as (x-2). But where d you get $x^3-2x-1$ from?

Comment: $x^3+6x^2+4x+2=x^3-2x-1+6x^2+6x+3=x^3-2x-1,$ which has root $-1$, which is $2$ of course.

Comment: ahh, okay so it is about manipulations, I will try to play around with it. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You already have an answer for the first two cases. In $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, your polynomial is just $2+x+x^3$, which has a root: $2$. Therefore, it is not irreducible.

Comment: Ahh I see, So the answer to Z3 is that , it is not possible to write it as a product of irreducibles? Because it there exist a root

Comment: @Djhoe No! The conclusion is that $x^3-2x+1=(x-2)(x^2+x-1)$. And $x^2+x-1$ is irreducible, since it is a quadratic polynomial withou roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: How do you get the factor $(x^2+x-1)$ I try to let $p(x)(x-2)=x^3-2x+1$ $\implies p(x)=x^2+2x+2$

Comment: @Djhoe I made a mistake. It should be $x^2-2x+1=(x-2)(x^2-x-1)$. Sorry about that. I hope that all is well now.

Comment: that makes sense thank you